# Get data-reactid with BeautifulSoup

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want the Code that gives me the change since yesterday of the stock. Right now that would be roughly +5 (+0.59%). What the code returns is : +110$

```
def tesla_deltaTracker():  
            url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/TSLA/"
            response = requests.get(url)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
            price = soup.find('span', {"data-reactid":'33'}).text
            return (price)
```

Answer (score 2):

there's more than 1 tag with that `data-reactid` attribute. you want the 2nd one

```
price = soup.find_all('span', {"data-reactid":'33'})[1].text
```

Comment: thank you so much! I got really frustrated you saved my day